# Lazy Loading of an attribute leading to a null pointer exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have an attribute inside my entity which is being loaded in a lazy way, this property itself could be null hence I cant directly go ahead and perform any operation on this and also since this is lazy loaded, a null check is not helping me out.

Example :

parent.getChild().getContent() != null

here my child is lazy laoded, and there is a chance that getChild would itself return me null hence getContent() will lead to NPE.

putting a null check above this line of code would also not help as parent.getChild() would be null as this is lazy loaded initially.

Answer (score 0):

Since lazy-loading will occur when you call `getChild()`, before the null-check is executed, this will not be an issue. Do your null-check as you need it to be, `getChild()` will only return null if it is actually null.